# pd.read_fwf() vs pd.read_table() giving discrepancies when reading a large file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file-io

```
 df = pd.read_table("/media/jaideep/4F95-2DF2/test.txt", header = 11, delimiter = "|",encoding = "latin1", low_memory = False, comment = "#")
```

produces a DataFrame of dimensions: [1100563 rows x 56 columns]

while,

```
 df = pd.read_fwf("/media/jaideep/4F95-2DF2/test.txt", header = 11, delimiter = "|",encoding = "latin1",comment = "#")
```

produces a DataFrame of dimensions: [1100654 rows x 10 columns]

There is a difference of 100 rows that i need to account for using pd.read_table() as the input file is not a fixed width file

-Please point me in the right direction with the possible reasons as to why pd.read_table() is skipping the 100 rows.Thanks!!

Comment: There is also difference with number of columns. This depends of data, is possible share file if not confidental?

Comment: You don't care that it's also dropping 46 of your columns?!

Comment: I'm not interested in using read_fwf() cause of loss of columns, but i used it to just compare the dimensions @smci

Comment: yeah i cant share the file...@jezrael

Comment: You could anonymize the first 5 row of each file

Comment: df = pd.read_table("/home/jaideep/data1.txt",header = 11, delimiter ="\ |", low_memory = False). I just stumbled upon this but when i set the delimiter = "\|" instead of just delimiter = "|" i get the missing rows @smci

Comment: @jaideepseth: Well done for fixing the issue, that sounds like a bug on read_fwf. Check the [open issues on read_fwf](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/search?q=read_fwf&state=open&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) and if it's new, please do file a bug. Just create some tiny snippet input file that illustrates the problem. Also, what version of python, pandas and OS platform are you on?

Comment: Python 3.6.3, Ubuntu 16.04 & '0.22.0'
please check if my answer seems like a plausible reason. Thanks!!@smci

Answer (score 0):

Note that `read_fwf()` is also dropping 46 of your columns, which surely matters too. Just eyeball say rows 1..4 and see if you can spot the difference.

Anyway, the obvious way to spot the difference is to (visually) binary-search: visually compare `df1[1:n]` and `df2[1:n]` (or `df1[n]` to `df2[n]`) until you see where it inserts/drops rows. Start n small, say n=5, and increase it progressively until you find the lines mismatching.

Comment: jaideep, have you tried this then? You don't need to post the lines, but tell us what you see. Are the first n=5 lines identical, at least in the first 10 columns, or not?

Comment: the first 10 lines are identical in all respects other than the data contained.

Comment: Sorry, how can they be "identical in all respects other than the data contained"?!? Do you mean the data is the same, just that it's split between cols 1..10,11..56?

Comment: Please suggest some other methods to identify the dropped rows.Thanks!!'

Comment: number of rows, categories under which data is NAN etc

Comment: I completely don't understand you. Are the first 10 rows identical or different? Is the difference merely in the column split? or the column datatypes?

Comment: Anyway, if they're essentially identical, then just try n=20,50,100,200,500,1000... etc until you find discrepancies. Step n back until you identify which line the discrepancy first appeared.

Answer (score 0):

`df = pd.read_table("/home/jaideep/data1.txt",header = 11, delimiter ="\ |", low_memory = False)`

Setting the delimiter = "\ |" instead of delimiter = "|" worked for me.

The pandas.read_table() documentation states:

Delimiter to use. If sep is None, will try to automatically determine this. Separators longer than 1 character and different from ‘s+’ will be interpreted as regular expressions, will force use of the python parsing engine and will ignore quotes in the data. Regex example: ‘rt’

so perhaps the metacharacter backslash, . As in Python string literals, the backslash can be followed by various characters to signal various special sequences. It’s also used to escape all the metacharacters so you can still match them in patterns; for example, if you need to match a [ or \, you can precede them with a backslash to remove their special meaning: [ or \.

Answer (score 0):

`read_table` is deprecated, use `read_csv` instead.

This is [official](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html).

For reference:

> `read_csv`
>       Read a comma-separated values (csv) file into DataFrame.
>
> `read_fwf`
>       Read a table of fixed-width formatted lines into DataFrame.